# canvas toDataURL for uploaded file throws security error on same domain

Tags: javascript, html, security, canvas

so you select an image via the file input, the selected image file gets gets turned into a window.url.createobjecturl and passed to a hidden "img" element unmodified, then a preview of the image element's current data is rendered into a canvas element. so far, so good. but then when i try to render the canvas.toDataURL i keep getting that aggravating security exception about it being insecure. this happens on chrome and firefox.

understand that this is a file OBJECT that was select with an html INPUT element, and NOT via a "file://" url, and the webpage is an actual webpage, and is loaded via "http://" and not via "file://".

the image file has not even left the browser yet to go to the server, so there should not be any domain issues. it's just a raw blob being asserted as the source to an image, which is then telling the canvas to update its preview, which it does. after that, when trying to saved the canvas contents, the browser triggers an error.

i have read all of the specs regarding scenarious where the canvas element becomes tainted, and this scenario does not meet ANY of those scenarios.

i've seen a similar example on mozilla demos of some one offering code snippets to show people how to do the same thing, but i have not seen if any one had problems with it.

any ideas? TIA

#

=== UPDATE ===

#

okay, i've figured out what the PROBLEM is, but i'm still not clear on WHY it's a problem. here's the setup:

1) page is called via, eg, "example.com/"

2) script is called via: "r.example.com/script.js"

3) if script loads ANY image from "r.example.com", to use for the PAGE DESIGN, and NOT the canvas, it some how taints the entire page. in this case i draw the entire page via javascript, so the header image is tainting the rest of the page. if i change the header image to come from "example.com" instead of "r.example.com", the problem with the canvas complaining about not being secure goes away, and everything is fine.

what i don't understand is WHY this is happening. the header image is being loaded from the same place as the javascript file, and, for the sake of argument i even set the access-control-allow-origin to "*", for both the main domain and the subdomain, which makes no difference.

so, access control is allowed from anywhere, the header image is coming from the same place as the javascript file, and it is NOT being drawn to the canvas (that's a user file), so why would drawing the header image via javascript taint a canvas that it has nothing to do with??? also, the css and other media are loaded from the same subdomain, but this does not affect the page, so long as the script did not load them [o_0].

i want to keep all of my resources on a separate subdomain for scalability, so, this issue is frustrating, because i don't quite understand why it's still happening...

Answer (score 1):

If you want your image to be on a separate subdomain, you have to change the origin of the image to allow all subdomains like this:

```
img .origin = '*.mydomain.com'
```

I'm using canvas with kineticJS and just tested it myself.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that you have to set this property on the image object itself, as it has no domain initially [o_0]

```
img.origin = 'mydomain.com'
```